# Entity State Value cant be null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have two tables orders and order detail and i have order foriegn key in order detail. and i am inserting ordertotal into order table and all other order info in order details but i am getting this error .please help me out and please tell me hw to use entity state to add values to foriegn key table.

[image]

and here is my saveorder controller function

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveOrder(FormCollection fc)
     {
        ResturantContext context = new ResturantContext();
        ShoppingCart myCart = (ShoppingCart)Session[WebUtil.CART];
        User u = (User)Session[WebUtil.USER];
        Order order = new Order();



        order.TotalAmount = myCart.TotalAmount;
        new OrderHandler().AddOrder(order);

        foreach (var m in myCart.Items)
        {
            OrderDetails od = new OrderDetails();
            od.ID = m.Id;
            od.Price =m.Price;
            od.Product_name = m.Name;
            od.Quantity = m.Quantity;
            od.Address = fc["Address"];
            od.City = fc["City"];
            od.DateOfOrder = DateTime.Now;
            od.UserName = u.FullName;
            od.Email = u.Email;

            od.ContactNo = fc["ContactNo"];
            od.Country = fc["Country"];

           new OrderHandler().AddOrderDetails(od);

        }
        Session.Remove(WebUtil.CART);
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
```

Comment: Does `od.Order` have a value or is it null as the exception suggests? Why assume this has to do with the entity state? Check the exception's call stack to see where the exception was actually raised. I suspect it's inside the `Entry()` method. Post the *full exception* in the question itself, including the call stack. You can get it easily with `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: od.order has no value but i dont know how to add foriegn keyvalue  to table using entity states .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`od.Order` will always be `Null` since you are not setting it anywhere in your code. Try at least set it like `od.Order = order` inside your loop before calling your `OrderHandler().AddOrderDetails(od);`